# How to see the contents of dropdown after closing the error popup when a program crashes?

Tags: windows-7, crash

I had a program crash on me and pop up the following screen (with different exe name of course):

[image]

I closed the popup but now I would like to see the content under the "view problem details" dropdown. Is there a way of finding this?

Comment: Check out the Event Viewer. Read [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/)

Answer (score 1):

Often a program writes a description of error conditions to the Windows Event Log. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and type *event* in the search box. Select the *Event Viewer*.

Select *Action*, *Filter Current Log* and check the *Critical* and *Warning* types. For Windows *Scheduled Tasks*, it's likely the error mesage is in the *System* log, but you may need to check others, as well.
[image: Filtering Event Log]

It also depends on what application *Task Manager* was attempting to run. Not all applications use the Windows Event Log, and there may be a local error report (e.g. Mozilla reports which can be sent to their support staff).